# What is the difference between 真确 and 真实?

Tags: meaning, usage, difference

Is 真确 and 真实 used in different situations? Do provide some examples on their usage if possible. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

"真确" is usually **not** used in Mandarin now.

As a native, I only confirmed that it is in fact a word through a search on the Internet.

Comment: If "千真万确" is still in use, I don't see why '真确' isn't

Comment: How is that related. @T

Comment: 千真万确  means  " 十分真确 ". so "真确"  has to be a thing;  just like "千辛萬苦" means "十分辛苦 ", '辛苦' has to be a thing.

Comment: @TangHo I think it's because「眞」is more commonly used for the meaning *very* in Mandarin, like「眞熱」and「眞棒」.「眞 què」is likely to be misunderstood.

Comment: 真确 is just less common nowadays in Mandarin, but it is there. [link](http://cd.hwxnet.com/view/licljjknbnopcnek.html)

Answer (score 3):

As a native speaker, fefe has never heard of this term may prove it is rarely used in Mandarin. However, as a Cantonese speaker,  真确 is a very common term to me.

> 真实 (adj): true
>
> 真确 (adv): truly and accurately ; in truthful and certain manner

Example for 真确 (adv):

看得真确 = truly and accurately see it

說得真确 = sounds truthful and certain

Example for 真实 (adj):

真实内容 = the true content

真实想法 = the true thinking